# Decode specific Json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying decode a json, using `json_decode`.
I need get only 2 informations of json: `title` and `id`.

This informations are related to product. But my problem is, "inside of" each `Product`, have `images` and each image have a `title` also.

My doubt is: how get "title" (only related to product)?

Code at the moment:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);


$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($result, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {

    echo $val['title'];

}
```

JSON example:

http://freetexthost.com/kfoki4cy03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` at all. Because `json_decode()` with the second parameter == `true` gives back an associative array, simply traverse it like so:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
if (is_array($json) && count($json) 
    && is_array($json['products']) && count($json['products']))
{
    foreach($json['products'] as $aProduct)
    {
       $id = $aProduct['id'];
       $title = $aProduct['title'];

       ...
    }
}
```